# Remote MSSQL/ODBC Syncing With Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, synchronization

I am working with a client that has data in an MSSQL database. I only have read access to a remote ODBC connection and cannot modify the database in any form.

I'd like to replicate a subset of the data locally in an open-source alternative, syncing once per day or so. This is largely to eliminate reads against the data during peak hours. The local data will be used in a Rails 4 application. Note that syncing only needs to be one-way, as I don't have write access.

1. How can I best accomplish this?
2. FreeTDS?
3. Are there any libraries that will help with the syncing, or can I expect to write all the glue code myself?

Comment: Had the same problem. Could you share what you used in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to create a ruby script that can be scheduled to do the data retrieving.
In order to connect to the MSSQL database, please take a look at this [simple project](https://github.com/fidalgo/ruby-mssql-example) I've created.

Then you only need to code the data you want to retrieve and the way you store it.

I prefer the approach of being decoupled from your rails application, although you can use a scheduler like [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) or [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) and run it with your application.